# Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, grub2, dual-boot, windows

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 as a dual boot with Windows 7 (64bit). Everything was fine yesterday, but when I am unable to boot Windows 7 after tried to boot. Windows couldn't fix it and neither did system restore.

Here's the [pastebin of boot-repair](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1260793/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to run Boot repair for Windows, If you have an HP simply boot into your recovery partition and select start-up repair, if not you must insert your install disc and from there choose start-up repair.

Comment: Hi Thanks for getting back...I have a HP Pavillion desktop, but it did not come with a recovery disc. I don't know how to boot into the recovery partition and select start-up repair.

Comment: When Grub opens you should have 2 windows loaders, one is the actual OS the other is the recovery tool, try running that, and as I said it will be "Startup repair."

Comment: When I try the recovery tool and startup repair it still doesnt work it just tries fixing and says unable to do so and then sends me back to the boot manager screen where I have the choice of Win7 and Ubuntu.

Comment: I did sudo update-grub
and the grub.cfg files says: Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-31-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Skipping Windows 7 (loader) on Wubi system
Found Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda3
Skipping Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on Wubi system
done
Is there a problem with wubi?

Answer (score 0):

Try to [repair Windows 7 booting](http://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/RepairWindows7Booting.html) either by creating Windows 7 Recovery CD/USB or downloading and burning a Windows 7 Installation USB/DVD (download links are given on page).

Once you have Windows running again you can reinstall Ubuntu GRUB/wubi.